# What does it mean by saying that future achieves implicit synchronization?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, programming-languages, future

From [Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott](https://books.google.com/books?id=GBISkhhrHh8C&pg=PA634&lpg=PA634&dq=%22Implicit%20synchronization%22%20future&source=bl&ots=GkRg6R9rOv&sig=GcX6wvZ83D9Ws7blsxypeYmRq5g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinseva4f_WAhVHbiYKHSPiAdMQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22Implicit%20synchronization%22%20future&f=false)

> **13.4.5 Implicit Synchronization**
>
> In several shared-memory languages, the operations that threads can
>   perform on shared data are restricted in such a way that
>   synchronization can be implicit in the operations themselves, rather
>   than appearing as separate, explicit operations.
>
> We have seen one example of implicit synchronization already: the
>   forall loop of HPF and Fortran 95 (Example 13.10). Separate iterations
>   of a forall loop proceed concurrently, semantically in lock-step with
>   each other: each iteration reads all data used in its instance of the
>   ﬁrst assignment statement before any iteration updates its instance of
>   the left-hand side. The left-hand side updates in turn occur before
>   any iteration reads the data used in its instance of the second
>   assignment statement, and so on. Compilation of forall loops for
>   vector machines, while far from trivial, is more or less
>   straightforward. On a more conventional multiprocessor, however, good
>   performance usually depends on high-quality **dependence analysis,
>   which allows the compiler to identify situations in which statements
>   within a loop do not in fact depend on one another, and can proceed
>   without synchronization**.
>
> **Futures**
>
> **Implicit synchronization can also be achieved without compiler analysis**. ...
>
> Using C#’s Task Parallel Library (TPL), we might write
>
> ```
> var description = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDescription());
> var numberInStock = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetInventory());
> ...
> Console.WriteLine("We have " + numberInStock.Result
> + " copies of " + description.Result + " in stock");
> ```
>
> Static library class `Task.Factory` is used to generate futures, known
>   as “tasks” in C#. The Create method supports generic type inference,
>   allowing us to pass a delegate compatible with `Func<T>` (function
>   returning `T`), for any `T`. We’ve speciﬁed the delegates here as
>   lambda expressions. If `GetDescription` returns a `String`,
>   description will be of type `Task<String>`; if `GetInventory` returns
>   an `int`, `numberInStock` will be of type `Task<int>`.

The book lists future under the section of implicit synchronization, which also contains both independent iterations in a for-loop and future.

1. Does "implicit synchronization" mean no need for synchronization?
2. What does it mean by saying that future (e.g. C#'s task)  achieves implicit synchronization?
3. In C#, do a task and the main program which starts it proceed
   without the need of synchronization between each other?

   Is a future used only when   the computation of the future and the
   main program which creates the future don't need synchronization
   between each other?

Thanks.

Comment: This is by far the simplest synchronization you can think of, the Task.Result property getter does the moral equivalent of Thread.Join().  Ensuring that the thread executing the task has completed and the Result is computed.  So the WriteLine call is blocked until both tasks complete.  Nothing much to it.  There is no additional synchronization between the two tasks and if they step on each other then it does go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronization in this context means (quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science))):

> Process synchronization refers to the idea that multiple processes are
>   to join up or handshake at a certain point, in order to reach an
>   agreement or commit to a certain sequence of action

`Task` (as an example of "future" concept) provides a way to start concurrent process and obtain its result in future, by accessing `Result` property (it does not *always* start concurrent process, but it does not matter here). So by calling `Result` you achieve synchronization between your current thread of execution and concurrent thread of execution represented by `Task` (because your thread potentially waits for task to complete). It's implicit because you just access regular property not using special synchronization constructs. Compare that to signalling with `ManualResetEvent` - you achieve the same goal but it's explicit this time.